# Is it possible to join unified group using rest api

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Users can navigate to private group page in outlook.office.com and then click join button to request access to group.

Is there an API to programmatically create access requests or navigate to a group page so that join action would be already open?

Comment: Seems that there is no api but could use Add member api "/groups/{id}/members/$ref"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for joining groups. You need to add users with "/groups/{id}/members/$ref".

Comment: This worked fine for me, however make sure the Group you're joining is public. Wasted so many hours trying to test against a Private group :(